Trouble Retrieving YouTube Channel Report with Google Analytics API: 403 Forbidden Error
I want to generate a report for a YouTube channel for which I have administrator access, using the Google Analytics API. (I'm not channel owner.)
However, when executing the following code in GAS, I receive a 403 Forbidden error.
const channels = YouTube.Channels.list('id,contentDetails', {
  id: "hogehoge"
});
const channelId = channels.items[0].id;

const oneMonthInMillis = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
const today = new Date();
const lastMonth = new Date(today.getTime() - oneMonthInMillis);

const metrics = [
  'views',
];
const result = YouTubeAnalytics.Reports.query({
  ids: 'channel==' + channelId,
  startDate: formatDateString(lastMonth),
  endDate: formatDateString(today),
  metrics: metrics.join(','),
  dimensions: 'day',
  sort: 'day',
});

I am referring to the documentation at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/youtube-analytics?hl=ja.
How can I retrieve the report? Or is this issue related to permissions and therefore, data cannot be output?

You need to ensure your script is requesting the correct scopes when using the YouTube APIs. Check that you're using the appropriate scopes for YouTube Data and YouTube Analytics.
Here are the scopes needed:
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly'

Add these scopes in the manifest file (appsscript.json) of your Google Apps Script project:
{
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly"
  ]
}

You can also check if you're retrieving the correct channel ID:
const channels = YouTube.Channels.list('id', {mine: true}); // use "mine: true" to ensure it's your authorized channel
const channelId = channels.items[0].id;

